# Why Spring Data fetching additional data when i declared fetchType of relation as lazy

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am struggling a little bit with hibernate/spring data.
I have pretty simple entities `User` and `Roles` and between those two I have `@ManyToMany` relation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

And

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And when I am getting data with the help of spring data I am getting additional query to `Role` table. Why is that? I specified it as `LAZY`, so query should be done when I need this data.

`cascade` is set because i am initializing data in main class and it is easier to write

`userRepository.save(new User("root", "root", "root1", "123", Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER"), new Role("ROLE_USER2"), new Role("ROLE_USER3"))));`

Code used to get data from db. This method or `findAll` results in the same behaviour. And it is called in empty controller/service without anything else.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Lets say I am calling this from test
Service method:

```
 @Transactional //without transactional annodation I am getting LazyInitializationException 
    public Set<DocumentProvider> extract(){
        User root2 = userRepository.findByEmail("root2");
        System.out.println("test1");
        root2.getRoles().forEach(role -> System.out.println("test2"));
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
```

and 'testing' method

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ExportServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ExportService exportService;
    
    @Test
    public void test(){
        exportService.extract();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that gets the data from the database? Thanks

Comment: @JoãoDias Code added. Repository is called in empty service just to check behaviour.

Comment: But which is the trigger for the database call? A REST call?

Comment: Yes, REST call.

Answer (score 1):

Since the trigger of the database call is a REST call, what is happening is that Jackson will then serialize the complete `User` object to include in the response and as a consequence the additional query to retrieve `roles`.

You should be able to confirm this by annotating `roles` with `@JsonIgnore`.

---

**Update after additional code added**

In your Service `extract()` method you have `root2.getRoles().forEach(role -> System.out.println("test2"));`. This will trigger the call to database because you are calling the getter `getRoles()`.

Comment: Is it going to serialize object which is not returned as json? I am using REST call only for testing purposes. And what I am returning from controller method is `Collections.emptyList()`

Comment: Can you please include the complete Controller and Service code then?

Comment: I think it would be easier/clearer if I post `@SpringBootTest`. Controller/service does not make sense

Comment: Check my updated answer ;)

Comment: I do agree with that, but query should be called whenever we call `getRoles` but instead of thet it is called whenever i call repository method. Even when I comment this code I am getting the same result. :(

Comment: Then I run out of ideas :(